# App always terminates in main.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.2 jumps to main.m every time after stopping simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682277/xcode-4-2-jumps-to-main-m-every-time-after-stopping-simulator)

Whatever a new crashing error I come across, it always seems to terminate in main.m. It will show the correct error, but highlight the this line in main.m

```
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

It's making things a bit hard to debug. Do I need to change some settings to get it to highlight the the correct bit of code?

Comment: try turning [NSZombies](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682277/xcode-4-2-jumps-to-main-m-every-time-after-stopping-simulator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321184/xcode-always-stopping-at-main-m-after-a-crash

Comment: this link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288492/standard-arguments-in-main-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You can add an Exception Breakpoint by opening up the Breakpoint Navigator pane, and clicking on the X button in the bottom left corner"

from this [more detailed instruction](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/)